# What's the syntax for getting an observable (rx.net) from an entity framework core 2 dbcontext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I can get an enumerable (working) like so:

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {

        return _context.Set<T>().AsEnumerable();
    }
```

But I'd rather get the Observable instead of the Enumerable so I can act upon each as they are received and stream in. `IQueryable.AsStreaming` used to do this. So something like that? I'm having a hard time finding documentation on this.

Comment: What do you need to observe?

Comment: @gabba The stream of entities from the database. I ended up using AyncEnumerable .ToObservable().